# History command isn't recognized as an internal command in child_process

Tags: bash, git, shell, child-process

I'm trying to make a hook for Github in js.
So I need to get the previous command, but `child_process` doesn't recognize the `history` command, which runs fine in my windows git bash.

This is the code I have

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

exec('history 2', (err, res, er) => {
  console.log(res)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`history` is no a program (not a binary or a script) but a [command builtin into `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html#index-history). You only can run it with `bash` — and only interactively:

```
$ bash -c "history 2"
(no output because it's non-interactive)
```

In a non-interactive session you have to read the history before using it:

```
$ bash -c "history -r && history 2"
the previous command
the last command
```

My advice is to use [`fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html#index-fc) instead of `history`. With `fc` you can select one command to show. For example to get the previous command use index `-2`:

```
$ bash -c "history -r && fc -ln -2 -2"
the previous command
```

Comment: That command ended up like this: [screenshot](https://ibb.co/g7TR1XF)

Comment: Try `bash -c "history -r && fc -ln -2 -2"` from the command line. It works in Linux but I know nothing about w32 and `git-bash`.

Comment: yeah, it works in windows `git-bash` but not through **exec** `child_process`

Comment: How do run it? Is it `exec('bash -c "history -r && fc -ln -2 -2"'` ?

Comment: yes, without the double quote. you can have a look at my questions js code.

Comment: Double quotes are important for `bash`!